# next.js shallow routing different pages

Tags: routes, react-router, next.js, next-router

I want to add routes to my next Project, but can't use shallow-router for different pages.
For example, I want to switch from /s/:id to /p/:id, without re-Render the page, just like I'm still at the same URL.
My project is already built, and I only want to add routing, but it's not allowed, [as the docs shows](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing#caveats).

**I know it shouldn't work, but What is the Alternative way to do it?**

Comment: Those are different routes so it's not possible. What's the use-case here? Why would you want to do that in the first place?

Comment: @juliomalves The project is already built up (with no url routing), I have something like Google Maps, where user can click on place and move back to the whole map view, so when user click on place, I want the route to move to domain/p (place), and when user move back to the map, I want the route to be domain/m.